# SchematicsException when creating an angular library with NX Commands

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nrwl-nx

I updated my NX Workspace to the latest version (`"@nrwl/angular": "11.5.2"`) using it with Angular apps (v 11.2.6) in a monorepo.

I would like to generate a new Angular library using the following command:

```
ng generate @nrwl/angular:library --name=service --style=scss --directory=/libs/booking
```

But I receive the following error in the console:

```
SchematicsException [Error]: Project name "-libs-booking-service" is not valid.
New project names must start with a letter, and must contain only alphanumeric 
characters or dashes. When adding a dash the segment after the dash must also
start with a letter.
```

Somehow **the command adds a dash `-` before the project name**, generating the error.

I also wiped out the node_modules and reinstalled the packages again, but without any luck.

---

**UPDATE**

I leave below the steps that helped me to fix the issue after the hint from Shashank :

If I remove the leading `/` in the directory parameter, I get the following error:

```
ng generate @nrwl/angular:library --name=services --style=scss --directory=libs/booking

TypeError: Cannot read property 'paths' of undefined
```

That it is due to the tsconfig.json that for NX should still be `tsconfig.base.json`. By renaming it (temporarily) the command works.

Comment: Can you try `ng generate @nrwl/workspace:library --name=service --style=scss --directory=libs/booking`

Comment: There was a combination of leading slash and the tsconfig file name. If you write an answer  I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, I think below command works for you.Your `directory` had `/libs/booking`, which should have been `libs/booking`

```
ng generate @nrwl/workspace:library --name=service --style=scss --directory=libs/booking
```

Answer (score 0):

### Generate an application

Run `ng g @nrwl/angular:app my-app` to generate an application.

When using Nx, you can create multiple applications and libraries in the same workspace.

### Generate a component

npx nx generate @nrwl/angular:component my-component --project=your-app --module=/apps/your-app/src/app --no-interactive

Run `npx nx generate @nrwl/angular:component my-component --project=your-app --module=/apps/your-app/src/app --no-interactive` to generate a new component.

### Generate a library

Run `ng g @nrwl/angular:lib my-lib` to generate a library.

### Build

Run `nx build your-app` to build the project. The build artifacts will be stored in the `dist/` directory.

### Running unit tests

Run `ng test your-app` to execute the unit tests via [Jest](https://jestjs.io).

Run `nx affected:test --codeCoverage --skip-nx-cache` to execute the unit tests affected by a change.

### Understand your workspace

Run `nx graph` to see a diagram of the dependencies of your projects.

For existing projects with all '@nrwl' packages make sure you download npx if you haven't already.